# Using R's nleqslv to solve system of equations with vector values

Tags: r, vectorization

I want to solve a system of nonlinear equations in which some terms are vectors. For example:

> x[1] * x[2] - exp(-1/Temp) = 0
>
> x[1] - x[2] + f(x[1], x[2], Temp) = 0

where *Temp* is a vector and *f* is some complicated function. Can this be done with R's nleqslv?

Comment: So Temp is the data and you are trying estimate two parameters with two equations. Seems doable. Why not offer a test case with some data and a prototypical function?

Comment: If you're concerned about `f(x)`, start with something simple like `f(a,b,c) a+b+c` to verify that the solver does what you expect.  BTW, you could also try `BB:bbsolve` as an alternative solver.

Comment: Rather, I want to solve for x[1] and x[2] for *each* value of Temp, where Temp is, for example, Temp = seq(2000, 2500, 10).

Comment: In that case, something like `sapply(1:length(temp),function(j) nlseq(stuff, Temp[j]) )`

Comment: That's an elegant solution. Will try it out. Thanks!